# How to sort list of directories in custom order that follows the calendar month name

Tags: vb.net

I have this list of directories:

JAN_20

FEB_20

MAR_20

.....

DEC_20

I am reading it using the following VB.Net code:

```
 Private Const MY_PATH As String = "\\120.199.10.39\departments\2020\"
 Dim Z_directories = Directory.GetDirectories(MY_PATH, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList()

 For Each dir1 In Z_directories 
     'do something
 Next
```

The issue is that I would like to "OrderBy" it in a custom way that follows the month order (Jan, Feb, Mar,... etc), not alphabetically or by creation time, etc.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'sort it' ? Do you mean you want to process them in month order?

Comment: yes, exactly. I mean "OrderBy" natural calendar month order

Comment: What's the point in calling `ToList` on the result of `GetDirectories` when it's already an array? Why can't you just loop over the array?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Well, you can directly call `.Sort` on a List.  Maybe that's what was in OP's mind?

Comment: @SeanSkelly, yeah, and you can call `Array.Sort` and pass an array, so what's your point?

Comment: Your code indicates that you want to search subfolders of the specified folder path but is that really the case? It doesn't seem to make sense that you would.

Comment: @jmcilhinney What was missing from my comment (and probably all I should have said) was "sure, OP doesn't need to call `.ToList`, but it's not relevant to the main question".  I won't engage on this more as it's not helping anyone to continue down this road.  Both our comments were probably not necessary.

Comment: *"it's not relevant to the main question"*. That's why I put it in a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the thing you need to know here is that you can turn those folder names into `Date` values like this:

```vb
Dim d = Date.ParseExact(s, "MMM_yy", Nothing, DateTimeStyles.None)
```

That means that you can convert all your folder names to `Dates` and then sort by those `Dates`. There are a number of specific ways you can do the actual sort.

Here's an example that uses the array returned by `GetDirectories` and sorts it in place:

```vb
Dim rootFolderPath = "folder path here"
Dim subFolderPaths = Directory.GetDirectories(rootFolderPath)

Array.Sort(subFolderPaths,
           Function(sfp1, sfp2)
               Dim folderName1 = Path.GetFileName(sfp1)
               Dim folderName2 = Path.GetFileName(sfp2)
               Dim folderDate1 = Date.ParseExact(folderName1, "MMM_yy", Nothing, DateTimeStyles.None)
               Dim folderDate2 = Date.ParseExact(folderName2, "MMM_yy", Nothing, DateTimeStyles.None)

               Return folderDate1.CompareTo(folderDate2)
           End Function)
```

Here's a further example that uses a LINQ query to sort before creating a final array:

```vb
Dim rootFolderPath = "folder path here"
Dim subFolderPaths = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(rootFolderPath).
                               OrderBy(Function(sfp) Date.ParseExact(sfp, "MMM_yy", Nothing, DateTimeStyles.None)).
                               ToArray()
```

Note that the second example calls `EnumerateDirectories` rather than `GetDirectories`, so as to not create two different arrays. Note that you can also call `ToList` if you prefer a `List(Of String)` to a `String` array but I tend to advise using arrays unless you specifically need to add and/or remove items.

Comment: Thank you jmcilhinney, I am accepting your answer. Regards.

Comment: I have added a second example that you may or may not find preferable.

Comment: Yes, second example is better as it is more compact. Thank you again for taking the time to look into this!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
   Z_directories .Sort(Function(valueB, valueA) CDate(Right(valueB, 2) & "00-" & Mid(valueB, Len(valueB) - 5, 3) & "-" & "01").CompareTo(CDate(Right(valueA, 2) & "00-" & Mid(valueA, Len(valueA) - 5, 3) & "-" & "01")))
```